# Keras: Manually backprop from Discriminator to Generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I have a model that is essentially an Auxiliary Conditional GAN; the first part of the model is the Generator, the last part is the Discriminator.  The Discriminator makes multiclass (k=10) predictions.

Following the work of http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07768 (pp3 for a helpful diagram, but note I ignore network structure modifications for the purposes of this question) I train the entire model for T=32 iterations by generating synthetic input and class labels (The 'inner loop').  I can predict on real data and labels using just the Discriminator(Learner) to get losses.  However I need to back-propagate the Discriminator's error all the way back through the inner loop to the Generator.

How can I achieve this with Keras?  Is it possible to do loop unrolling in Keras?  How can I provide an arbitrary loss and backprop this down the unrolled layers?

Update: There's now one implementation, in PyTorch, which uses Facebooks 'Higher' library. This appears to mean that the updates made during the inner loop must be 'unwrapped' in order for the final meta-loss to be applied throughout the entire network. Is there a Keras way of achieving this? https://github.com/GoodAI/GTN

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **Generative Adversarial Network (GAN)** which both model learns; one is to *classify* and the other is for *generation*.
To summarize, the output of the Generator is fed as a Input in the Discriminator and then feeds back its output to the Generator as its Input.

There is also a discussion and implementation of this in TensorFlow Keras using **MNIST Digit** Dataset in TensorFlow GAN/DCGAN Documentation in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan).

Comment: Thanks, strictly speaking the model is an auxiliary conditional GAN, but the question is how to do the inner loop unrolling and backprop from an arbitrary loss as per the linked paper in Keras.